# ASCII dictionary in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to initialize a dictionary in python with keys as all the 128 ascii characters and values as their corresponding ascii values?

Comment: Sure it is. It is even trivial to do so. Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: yes, but have done only for uppercase and lowercase letters, and not for all the characters.

Comment: @Delgan: `{chr(i): i for i in range(128)}`.

Comment: doesn't work @delgan

Comment: @anjali: then please *share your research*, having a starting point from incomplete code is always better.

Comment: @anjali: and when something doesn't work for you, tell us what *does* happen and why that isn't what you wanted. Because Delgan's code *does* work and produce what you asked.

Comment: I have done the same @MartijnPieters, but it doesn't show in an order.

Comment: Note that the first 32 characters are not printable. So you can initialize a dictionary, but printing it might yields strange results.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, that nice, thank you. Feel stupid to have posted such an ugly and complicated code.

Comment: @anjali: dictionaries **have no order**. They are unordered mappings from key to value.

Comment: @Falko: Python has you covered; all container types use `repr()` for their contents when printing. Non-printable characters are shown as their escape sequences then, so a newline is `\n` and `chr(1)` becomes `\x01`.

Comment: Not that you *need* a dictionary, not when you could just use `chr(character)`.

Comment: @martijnpieters thank you. I'm new to python and started with dictionaries today. Will try to learn better. Thank you, again

Comment: @anjali: it's fine you are new to Python; but you are also new to asking good questions on Stack Overflow. Share your research so we can give you meaningful answers *way sooner*.

Answer (score 6):

```
asciiDict = {i: chr(i) for i in range(128)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ascii_dict = dict()
ascii_in_number = range(0,256)
for i in ascii_in_number:
    ascii_dict[str(i)] = chr(i)
print(ascii_dict)
```